# Efficient way of counting `FALSE` between `TRUE`

Tags: r

I have a logical vector

```
v <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

I want to count the number of `FALSE` between each `TRUE`.  For the above example, the desired results is

```
3 2 1 4
```

Ideally, the answer would not use an iterative approach.  My actual application is a much larger logical vector.  The more efficient the better.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `2 1 4`, or at least `3 2 1 4`?

Comment: @Pascal Thanks, you're right.  I Fixed it.

Comment: If you are trying to count those values of `FALSE` *between* each `TRUE`, as stated in the OP, your output should be 2, 1, 4. The first three `FALSE` are not enclosed by a `TRUE` on either side. This point is important because it also raises the question whether a series of `FALSE`should be included in the output if it occurs at the end without a `TRUE` entry as your last vector element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `rle` function, such as:

```
out <- rle(v)
out$lengths[!out$values]
# [1] 3 2 1 4
```

Associated with the `with` function:

```
with(out, lengths[!values])
# [1] 3 2 1 4
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot about `rle`

Answer (score 5):

```
diff(which(c(TRUE, v))) - 1
```

if you seek efficiency.

Comment: If the last entry of the vector is `FALSE`, this solution will omit the last sequence of `FALSE` entries. Whether this is a problem depends on the OP's desired output, which, IMO, is not stated clearly as I tried to explain in a comment above.

Comment: @RHertel Well, in that case, you can just enclose the sequence by `TRUE` as `c(TRUE, v, TRUE)`.

Comment: I agree. This, however, would alter the output of the example given in the OP to `3, 2, 1, 4, 0`, and one might need to interpret or remove the zero. It is a minor problem, but it depends on the context. If the length of the output is important for further evaluation , e.g., in a loop, the presence or absence of a zero could make a difference and might lead to errors that could be difficult to detect. This is not to criticize your answer, but I found it important to point out that there could be a problem.

Comment: @RHertel Your point is well-taken. I am blatantly assuming that `TRUE`s don't appear in a row, as in the OP's example.

Answer (score 2):

Although the matter is already settled, here is a C++ function that will boost it a bit further too, although being a bit cumbersome to write.

```
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)
cpp.fun <- cxxfunction(signature(x="logical"), plugin="Rcpp", body='
    int n = LENGTH(x);
    Rcpp::IntegerVector lengths(n);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(!LOGICAL(x)[i]){
            lengths[count]++;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    }
    lengths = Rcpp::head(lengths, count);
    return(lengths);
')
v <- runif(10000000) > .8
require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(a = with(rle(v), lengths[!values]),
               b = diff(which(c(TRUE, v))) - 1,
               c = cpp.fun(v))
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
    a 479.59042 543.26234 585.36910 558.24042 605.80794 863.5284   100
    b  75.82237  81.25428 103.31213  87.55149 131.09488 219.2535   100
    c  42.01732  44.69037  50.14274  45.80284  47.67927 102.3952   100
```

Comment: The `rle` function is not correct. You currently don't extract the vector of `values`. This will probably speed down the currently slow solution.

Comment: Speed-up is not so much dramatic for lengthy vectors. For vectors of length 100000, Rcpp solution is only 1.5 times faster at 0.0001s.

Comment: Are the results similar for longer vectors?

Comment: It seems that the the solutions converges towards that Rcpp gives you a 1.5~5 times speedup depending on the data (the more `TRUE` the better the speedup). Might not be enough to make you bother with Rcpp if you don't already know it well.